# delive linux shared libraries with static link

Tags: shared-libraries

Many times I noticed that shared libraries are provided with a symbolic link.
The symbolic link sometimes located near the real so file.
Can please tell why ?
Why not using the real file only ?

Thank you,
Zvika

Comment: "are provided with a static link." -- did you mean _symbolic_ link? What is a "static link" ?

Comment: You are right. I meant "symbolic link". For example:  libxml2.so -> libxml2.so.2.9.1 , libxml2.so.2 -> libxml2so.2.9.1, libxml2.so.2.9.1 . Only the last file is a real one.  What is the reason libs are delivered with such links ?

Answer (score 1):

This is done to facilitate external library versioning. You can read about it [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23824_01/html/819-0690/chapter5-5.html).

Comment: Thank you very much !